# How can i count the words from a richtextbox

Tags: c#

I want to make a program that counts as example the word "Me" from a richtextbox. How is this possible in c#. The code that i already have is that it loads a textfile.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
            richTextBox1.Text = filetext;
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\School\C#\DEEL 2\HW5\5.3 opdracht1\Sonnet 14.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, you can do it pretty easily. Simply split the text on whitespaces, and then filter the array for words matching what you want. Here's a sample:

```
string search = "Me";
int count = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ').Where(word => word == search).Count();
```

Comment: Sometimes it's not counting accurate, do you know why that is ````string search = textBox2.Text;
            int count = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ').Where(word => word == search).Count();

            textBox3.Text = count.ToString();````

Comment: @Poemko Do you have capital letters in your string that might not be found? or do you have whitespaces in textBox2.Text? You can try this modified version here: `string search = textBox2.Text.Trim().ToLower(); int count = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ').Where(word => word.ToLower() == search).Count(); `

Comment: When i have "Hello Hello Hello Hello" 4 times it counts 3

Answer (score 0):

Separete all the words and after that you can do whatever you want

```
//Variable to store your count
int n = 0;
string stringToCompare = "Me";
string[] data = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
for(int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
{
  if(data[i]==stringToCompare )
     n++;
}
Console.WriteLine($"Word {stringToCompare } has appeared {n} times");
```

If you dont want case sensitive try something like

```
if(data[i].ToUpper() == stringToCompare.ToUpper() )
      n++;
```